# How to set apache web server to generate rolling log files?

Tags: performance, logging, apache2

i have my application installed on a windows server, under apache web server. This project is facing a performance issue now, It is responding very slow. Web application is installed in Jboss, and apache webserver communicates with jboss via AJP protocol.

I am studying why this performance problem is hitting my web application.
Over period of one years, the log files generated by web server is sized to  > 4 GB. The log file is `mod_jk.log`

I am looking for options that i can do to upgrade the performance. like enable rolling log system for apache. How can I do this?

@Answer :

I have successfully configured the logrotate to work on my web server.

```
ErrorLog '|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/errors.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400'


CustomLog '|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400'
```

Thats all, My log files are new everyday :)

Regards;
Vijay Shanker

Comment: CustomLog needs an extra argument, e.g. "common":   CustomLog '|bin/rotatelogs.exe logs/access.%Y-%m-%d.log 86400' common